# Data exists but my program says 'No data exists for the row/column.'

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand, ms-access-2016

```
    private void recordFromTable()
    {
        String firstName = Environment.UserName.Split('.')[0];
        String lastName = Environment.UserName.Split('.')[1];
        String query = "SELECT LastUpdate FROM " + "EmployeeContact" + " WHERE EmployeeLastName='" + lastName + "' AND EmployeeFirstName='" + firstName + "'";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
                connection.Open();
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        labelLastUpdated.Text = reader.GetString(0).Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The exception thrown is **No data exists for the row/column.**

I opened the Access database and ran the same query (that my inspector showed while debugging) and I get a row back from the database.

All the fields in Access are "Short Text"

Comment: Are you sure that the column LastUpdate is not null?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there is no record which satisfies the `WHERE` condition specified and thus the said exception. To verify run this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
EmployeeContact 
WHERE EmployeeLastName= lastName 
AND EmployeeFirstName=firstName;
```

You may as well want to change your query to this

```
String query = "SELECT Nz(LastUpdate, 'NO DATA PRESENT') LastUpdate FROM " + "EmployeeContact" + " WHERE EmployeeLastName='" + lastName + "' AND EmployeeFirstName='" + firstName + "'";
```

Comment: If there is no record that satisfies the condition then the where loop is not executed (and COALESCE with Access?)

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the data exists, it seems to me that your firstName or lastName variables may not be getting assigned the values you believe they are or want them to.

Comment: Yes i have data because i ran the same query in Access and it worked. But I changed my code from reader.GetString(0).Trim(); to reader["columnName"].ToString().Trim() and it started working